# How to remove facet from category search facet in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In hybris how can I remove a facet from the left `category search facet` which is displayed in the left of the category page?

[image]

Basically, how can I remove the `Shop by category` facet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it from the SOLR configuration. This property will be indexed by the SOLR. Have a look into the `solr-configuration.impex` file, remove it and update your database.